# Declare VideoCapture as a global variable

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

I am trying to stream webcam at C++/CLI winform application with using picture-box.

With the help of timer,i can stream webcam on picture-box but `VideoCapture cap(0); Mat frame;` are declare continuously. How can i transfer these two to a button click and use inside this timer.

```
private: System::Void Timer1_Tick(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {

            VideoCapture cap(0);
            Mat frame;
            cap.read(frame);
            System::Drawing::Graphics^ graphics2 = pictureBox1->CreateGraphics();
            System::IntPtr ptr2(frame.ptr());
            System::Drawing::Bitmap^ b2 = gcnew System::Drawing::Bitmap(frame.cols,
                frame.rows, frame.step, System::Drawing::Imaging::PixelFormat::Format24bppRgb, ptr2);
            System::Drawing::RectangleF rect2(0, 0, pictureBox1->Width, pictureBox1->Height);
            graphics2->DrawImage(b2, rect2);
        
    }
```

Comment: Just define them as global variables, outside of any function or class? However, global variables are not a good habit, a possible better solution would be class *member* variables. At least if you only initialize these variables *once*. If you need to initialize or reset them each "timer tick" anyway then keep them as local variables.

Comment: Thanks for fast respond. When i tried define as global variables,a member of a managed class cannot be of a non-managed class type error is returned.

Comment: @EmirhanKahraman For future questions: C++ and C++/CLI are two different languages. Only use one of the tags.

Comment: @TedLyngmo thanks for feedback.It was very useful for me

Comment: @HansPassant I defined **VideoCapture^ Capture;** as  a member variable and it turns with a **handle to a non-managed class is not allowed** error and it also turned that **'^' cannt use cv::VideoCapture'**

Comment: Oh, it is an unmanaged class.  Make it `VideoCapture*` capture;  `new` in the constructor, `delete` when you close the form.  Google "emgu videocapture" to get somewhere useful, this is heading for a steep cliff.